# Fubini's theorem with unbounded but summable integrand

Tags: integration, convolution, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am studying the function
\begin{align*}
%\int_{-\infty}^\infty
x \rightarrow
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty
        \mathrm{arcsch} (|x-y|) \frac{2y^2+by-1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}
    \mathrm{d}y
%\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}$ is the indicator function.
$\mathrm{arcsch} (|x-y|)$ has log-singularity in $x=y$, $1/\sqrt{1-y^2}$ has $1/\sqrt{.}$ singularity
in $y=\pm 1$, so even for $x=\pm 1$ this integral is finite (in fact, I observe that it is even a continuous function, although I haven't managed to prove it should be). The integral of the absolute value of the integrand above will also be finite.

I have thus confidently applied Fubini's theorem to the double integral:
\begin{align*}
I :&= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty
        \mathrm{arcsch} (|x-y|) \frac{2y^2+by-1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}
    \mathrm{d}y
\mathrm{d}x
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
        \mathrm{arcsch} (|z|) \frac{2(x-z)^2+b(x-z)-1}{\sqrt{1-(x-z)^2}} \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}  
    \mathrm{d}z
\mathrm{d}x
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty
        \mathrm{arcsch} (|z|) \frac{2(x-z)^2+b(x-z)-1}{\sqrt{1-(x-z)^2}} \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}
    \mathrm{d}x
\mathrm{d}z
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty
    \mathrm{arcsch} (|z|) \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
        \frac{2(x-z)^2+b(x-z)-1}{\sqrt{1-(x-z)^2}} \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)} 
    \mathrm{d}x\,
\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}

Now, note that
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2y^2+by-1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)} \mathrm{d}y = 0$,
so I conclude that $I=0$.
However, this is not what numerical integration of the above definition of $I$ tells me (performing
quadrature first on $y$, then on $x$). Which is wrong: applying Fubini's theorem, or numerical integration?